# Entitiy framework Core in VB.NET - How?

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, sqlite, code-first

I am currently learning how to create a CodeFirst database in UWP using Sqlite from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started (4 min to read). I've followed the steps and everything worked just fine in C#. When translating the guide into VB.NET, however, I get an error stating that the `Blogs` table is not present in my database, as soon as I attempt to add data to it (Click the Add-Button).

> SqliteException: SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Blogs'.

In VB.NET, `Add-Migration MyFirstMigration` creates an additional (third) C# file called "20170729091234_MyFirstMigration.Designer.cs".

How do I get this microsoft-example to work in VB.NET?

My Model:

```
Public Class BloggingContext
Inherits DbContext
    Property Blogs As DbSet(Of Blog)
    Property Posts As DbSet(Of Post)

    Protected Overrides Sub OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder As DbContextOptionsBuilder)
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(String.Format("Data Source={0}", "Blogging.db"))
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Blog
    Property BlogId As Integer
    Property Url As String
    Property Posts As List(Of Post)
End Class

Public Class Post
    Property PostId As Integer
    Property Title As String
    Property Content As String
    Property BlogId As Integer
    Property Blog As Blog
End Class
```

MainPage.xaml.vb:

```
Private Sub Add_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Using _Context As New BloggingContext
        Dim Blog As New Blog With {.Url = NewBlogUrl.Text}
        _Context.Blogs.Add(Blog)
        _Context.SaveChanges() '!!This is where the error occurs!!

        Blogs.ItemsSource = _Context.Blogs.ToList
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub Page_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Using _Context As New BloggingContext
        Blogs.ItemsSource = _Context.Blogs.ToList
    End Using
End Sub
```

App.xaml.vb:

```
[...]
Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    Using _Context As New BloggingContext
        _Context.Database.Migrate
    End Using
End Sub
[...]
```

If you require any more Information, I will happily provide it.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be due to the created .cs files. When you convert the three files to .vb files, the desired tables are created and an entry is created in the EFMigrationsHistory table. I have manually converted the following files from cs to vb:

1. 20170819131117_Inital.cs
2. 20170819131117_Inital.Designer.cs
3. DB_ModelModelSnapshot.cs

And the cs files taken from the project and the vb added. If someone now knows how to run the add-migration command for vb, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Hi there, did you ever figure out how to run the `add-migration` command in vb.net?